# User setting to fix the text background color

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm coding with SQL in Visual Studio Code. I'm using the default font, Dark(Visual Studio). When my text is not highlighted/selected, it shows with a strange background color that shouldn't be there by default. What is the user setting to override this?

[image]

Comment: Can you check if you havn't install any extension

Comment: I would doubt that it's a package. I only have 11 packages, basically all of them with over one million downloads.

Comment: I was looking at the options to overide this. Which one would it be?https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

Comment: `textCodeBlock.background` this one you can check

Comment: I appreciate the help. Raj,  you were right. It appeared to be an extension

Answer (score 1):

This was a feature introduced to **SQLTools v0.22.2** to  indicate what code would be executed by **Run current query**:

https://github.com/mtxr/vscode-sqltools/issues/592

One proposed fix is to add this to your settings:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "sqltools.currentQueryBg": "#ff0000",
    "sqltools.currentQueryOutline": "#ff0000"
}
```

You will need to change the above colors accordingly. It's far from ideal, since you'll need to tweak the settings every time you change themes in VS Code.